# How to filter the search in stackoverflow?

Tags: support, tags, search

Hi I am new to this forum. I found out how great this site is. but I have questions on how to filter the search like for example, viewing search results of "PCM Format" that tagged with "DELPHI"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can search through tags using `[tag-name]` and then add a search term that you like.  For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[delphi]+pcm+format

I searched : `[delphi] pcm format`

Answer (score 4):

There is a link to the search help in the /faq , or ...

1. navigate to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search
2. press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the search box in the upper right to get to the help page